# is it possible to take Azure key vaults secretes to blob storage?

Tags: azure

Good morning!

want to take backup of azure key vaults secretes blob storage using power shell.
i,m able to take backup to my local machine. team any help? suggestion pls?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question according to [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Side remark: *Good morning*  is a bit strange on an international site.

Comment: From a security perspective I doubt it is good practice.

Comment: yes ur correct peter. actually looking to take backup of all secretes pushed to azure key vaults to blob storage using power shell script

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct mechanism to achieve this.  You will indeed need to have an intermediary PowerShell process to download the secrets and upload them to blob storage.

Using blob storage as a medium for backup is okay provided you fully understand the implications and mitigate the risks.  You should at the very least ensure your storage account resides in a different region to your KeyVault for continuity reasons, and have appropriate controls in place to prevent unauthorized access.  You must also appreciate that the transportation of secrets is ultimately protected by a RSA 2048-bit key encrypting key (KEK).  You should apply key equivalency principles when making consideration for the security of your secrets in transportation outside of the Microsoft network.  You should also consider the security of the machine from which you run PowerShell on.  Using an automation account in Azure to run the PowerShell using a service principal may be better.

To send a file to blob storage using PowerShell, please see this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell